# How I Use My Redeemed Free Credits from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Yesterday, I received an email from Amazon like this:

> Subject: "AWS Summit Online - Feedback Ninja USD$25 AWS Credits"
>
> "Thank you for participating and providing feedback at AWS Summit Online. We are pleased to inform you that as a Feedback Ninja, you have been allocated the USD$25 AWS credit code."

When I log in to my AWS account, I had redeemed it and now my account have credit like this:

[image: AWS Credits]

How I use my redeemed credits? Because I want to learn AWS with it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, start using your AWS server, but always keep informed yourself by using bill forecast. It will show you the upcoming bill value. 
Most important part is your credit will automatically consume from your bill value.

Comment: Do you mean, when I open my AWS, first click bill forecast? How if I don't have credit card? Can I still use AWS ?

Comment: You just start using aws after creating aws account. Your credit will automatically consume reference to your bill. I told you to use bill forecast only to analyze how much upcoming bill amount. E.g you have only 25$ as credit but you used or about to use $50 service of aws then your have to pay extra 25$ bill amount to aws by external methods. Bill forecast only help you to limit your aws expense.